# Where are the packages that we used to install with meteorite?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I was trying to get an example an working from this tutorial: http://g00glen00b.be/meteor-twitter-streaming/
Here's the Github url: https://github.com/g00glen00b/meteor-twitter-stream

It was written in Meteor 0.7 and it requires some packages so the instructions say to do this:

```
mrt add semantic-ui
mrt add npm
mrt add streams
mrt add momentjs
```

However, I have Meteor 0.9.4 and since 0.9 we're not supposed to use meteorite anymore, just add packages directly with the "meteor add #package#" command.

The problem is that none of the packages needed by this project can be found (npm, semantic-ui,streams,momentjs). I tried asking the original author of the code but he needs time to look into it.

So I thought I would ask the community. Any ideas?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the package migration to 0.9, many packages were automatically migrated under the `mrt` user. Thus, `meteor add mrt:<package>` might work.

The best way to find the package you're looking for is to search for it on Atmoshpere, e.g. https://atmospherejs.com/?q=semantic, https://atmospherejs.com/?q=moment etc.

So your install instructions should become:

```
meteor add nooitaf:semantic-ui meteorhacks:npm arunoda:streams mrt:moment
```

Note that [Arunoda is no longer maintaining `streams`](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-streams/issues/26), so you might want to look for an alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I did try searching and installing these packages from atmosphere but how did you know which where the correct ones? Some examples: "mrt:moment" or "mrt:momentjs"? "nooitaf:semantic-ui" or "richsilv:semant-ui"?

Comment: Oh, [I'm](https://github.com/tomrogers3/meteor-winston/issues/7) [Atmosphere](https://github.com/MixinLabs/meteor-flash/issues/5) [police](https://github.com/pinglamb/meteor-bootstrap3/issues/1#issuecomment-60533766) :)

Comment: Got it :-) Look like full time work. Thanks for your response, I've marked it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

locate the package [here](https://atmospherejs.com/)

or by typing:

> meteor search semantic
>   meteor search moment etc...

more information regarding this matter: [here](https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/08/26/meteor-090-new-packaging-system)

Comment: I did try searching for the packages in atmosphere but searching for "semantic-ui" (for example) returns 7 results by three different users. Kind of tough figuring out which is the correct one. Also, I tried for example "meteor add richsilv:semantic-ui" and it said "no such package".